# What actions are rate-limited, and why?

Tags: support, notifications, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

I've seen a number of time delay notifications on the sites. E.g.:

> you can only comment every x seconds

What are all the situations that have timing delays? After we are proven to not be bots, why are repeated delays necessary?

Comment: For whoever cares to write that canonical answer: [a link to the search limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96942/why-rate-limit-searches/96944#96944).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prove that you aren't a bot now, but you can't prove that you aren't a bot five minutes from now.

Comment: Are you suggesting that someone is replacing users with bots, and not telling them that the are replacements? If a bot doesn't know it's a bot, and can solve clever mangled-word puzzles, is it still a bot?

Comment: Just reuse the cookie from the browser and plug it to a spam bot. How easy is that to spam/DoS without the delay.

Answer (score 23):

It seems no one else is willing to do this, so here goes...

*In all situations where CAPTCHAs are involved, for users with at least 200 reputation, once a CAPTCHA is solved, another one will not appear for the next five minutes.  Exceeding 40 minutes to submit a question, answer, or edit would previously trigger a CAPTCHA, but this has since been [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/eliminate-the-captcha-on-long-questions-answers).*

### Asking questions

There is a limit of 50 questions within a rolling 30-day period and 6 questions within a rolling 24-hour period, including any questions asked within these periods later deleted; a question can only be posted once every 30 seconds, and users with less than 125 reputation are limited to one question every 20 minutes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask)). Additionally, [attempting to submit a question more than once every 60 seconds (for users with less than 10,000 reputation) or faster than 5 seconds after starting to ask will trigger a CAPTCHA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear/2293#2293).

### Answering questions

[Users with less than 125 reputation are limited to one answer every three minutes and cannot answer their own question within 8 hours of posting their question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23038/why-must-i-wait-three-minutes-after-posting-an-answer-to-post-another-answer)  There is no limit for users with at least 125 reputation, except that [attempting to submit an answer more than once every 60 seconds (20 seconds for 10K users) or faster than 5 seconds after starting to answer will trigger a CAPTCHA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear/2293#2293).

### Accepting answers

Users [must wait 15 minutes after asking a question to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post) and [must wait 48 hours after the question was asked to accept their own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer).

### Voting on posts

Normal users are limited to 30 votes (up or down) per day for all posts, plus 10 votes per day for questions only; the question-only votes cannot be used once the user has casted 25 votes on answers ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)).  [Downvotes on posts that are later deleted do not count toward this limit.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134200/moderators-can-vote-as-much-as-they-want)

### Searches

Normal users are limited to 6 searches per minute.  ♦Moderators are limited to 12 searches per minute.  [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118067/please-relax-the-search-rate-limits-for-moderators)

### Comments and comment votes

[Users are limited to posting one comment every 5 seconds.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-time)  Voting on comments, including deletion, [is limited to once every 5 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31455/wrong-message-you-may-only-submit-a-comment-every-five-seconds-when-deleting-m).  Fetching additional comments is [limited to once every 2 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5370/you-may-only-fetch-comments-every-2-seconds-causes-comment-fetch-failure).

### Editing and suggesting edits

[Users are limited to editing five of their own posts per day.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125372/should-the-5-edit-limit-prevent-you-from-hitting-edit-in-the-first-place)  [Unregistered users cannot suggest edits on posts less than 10 minutes old.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions/81701#81701)  Attempting to submit an edit [more than once every 30 seconds (10 seconds for 10K users) or faster than 5 seconds after starting an edit will trigger a CAPTCHA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear/2293#2293).

### Deleting posts

Users are limited to deleting five of their own posts per day.  [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85523/you-have-already-deleted-5-of-your-own-posts-today-further-deletes-are-blocked)

### Showing upvote/downvote totals (1K privilege)

Users are limited to fetching upvote/downvote totals once per second. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35488/you-may-only-fetch-vote-counts-once-every-second-is-really-set-for-30-seconds)

### Changing username

Users are limited to changing their username once every 30 days; users with accounts less than 2 days old may freely change their name. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names)

Comment: Chat search as well (I dunno the exact params that trigger it--it's sort of variable in the timeouts it gives)

Answer (score 0):

They're not just there to stop bots, but also anti-social users.

Comment: You stop anti-social users by preventing them from contributing too much?

Comment: Stop is a bit strong... limit might be better

Comment: I'm starting to think you're using a different definition of "anti-social" than the rest of the world.

Comment: Whoever invented the "inconvenience the many to stop the few" school of design deserves a swift kick to the crotch.

Comment: And anti-social users are known to mass-upvote comments?

Comment: @Manni more mass-downvote but yes, sometimes mass upvote

Comment: @TheTXI I'm using it the British way... sorry

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes... that's what they're for. I'm not saying I agree that they should be there (because I don't - I'd love to see them removed, at least once you hit a certain rep)

Comment: @Greg: The down votes are because people feel you are wrong. And you are.

Comment: @Rich B Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @Greg: No problem. I aim to please.

Comment: We have a saying over here that says *"I aimed to the belfry, but hit the priest."*

Comment: @voyager: Are you saying Rich B is a priest? I'm all confused.

Comment: @mmyers: Well if it is true that "You are what you eat", then yes.

Answer (score -3):

- Accepting your own answers. (24 hours). Aka "The Masturbation Clause"
- Accepting any answer (I think its 5 minutes). Aka "Fools Rush In"

Comment: Some references would be helpful here. I think it't 15 minutes for accepting answers, but I don't want to go link-hunting right now.

Comment: Well I discovered the "Masturbation Clause" on my own, you can try it yourself too!

Comment: Hmm, well, [in this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97425/reduce-accepting-own-answer-delay) it says 48 hours for self-accepts and 15 minutes for other accepts.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)