# "You may only fetch vote counts once every second" is really set for 30 seconds

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, vote-count

When you click to fetch vote counts too quickly you get the message "You may only fetch vote counts once every second". You actually have to wait 30 seconds before you can fetch another count.

*(Note that this only applies to users with >= 1000 rep)*

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the vote counts fetch?

Comment: @Vinko = click on the vote total to see the up/down totals.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next nightly build

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is there a limit on this anyway?

Comment: I tried finding a duplicate of my problem, and this is as close as I've gotten. I keep getting this dialog for viewing up/downvotes, flagging, closing and commenting, without even doing them _once_. I load a page, and can't do these things. It the randomly works after a while.  I didn't debug this thoroughly but at least no bogus requests were sent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The timer for up-voting comments is similarly busted. Damned "code re-use"!