# Comment Time Limit Increased?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please return the comment rate limit to a flat 30 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35501/please-return-the-comment-rate-limit-to-a-flat-30-seconds)

So it's now 15 seconds until you can post a new comment, I can accept that.  Resetting the timer every time you hit the informational message is a PITA.

I was looking at two answers that both recommended the same knee-jerk response

Comment: That's ok.  You can still post answers as fast as you want to.

Comment: And 15 seconds per comment isn't too bad - that's still 240 comments an hour.

Comment: Plus, if it takes you less than 15 seconds to write and proof read your comment, it may well not be worth posting.

Comment: Unless it's really, really funny.

Comment: But if you find that you need to post a lot of comments quickly, you probably aren't using the system correctly.

Comment: It also avoids turning SO into an instant chat room.

Comment: Which is a noble goal.

Comment: Not unlike the noble unicorn.

Comment: Shining - a beacon of perfection to all who gaze upon its lustre!

Comment: _*loads shotgun, heads out in search of unicorns*_

Comment: "You can still post answers as fast as you want to" well not really, you'll get CAPTCHA'ed

Comment: As humorous as this is, if there was a thread that needed the 1-click comment killer, this is probably officially it. :) (Sorry @Pollyanna ... )

Comment: @State: i can't believe this question hasn't been closed as a dupe yet.  maybe ... of this?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35501/please-return-the-comment-rate-limit-to-a-flat-30-seconds

Comment: @~quack: Oh yeah, forgot about that. Thanks; good call.