# How about "you may only submit 2 comment votes every 10 seconds"?

Tags: feature-request, comments, rate-limiting, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get x comment votes per x minutes, rather than one vote per 5 seconds?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-x-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds)

When reading a list of comments, it is common for me to decide what I will vote up, before I start clicking. This means I will often decide on two or three comments out of a list of 6 that I think are good.

Then I run into this message.

> You can submit a comment vote every five seconds.

It seems that changing the limiter to count every 2 (or 3) comments instead of every 1 would be more user friendly, and in the end have no negative impact on the spam prevention / server load reduction.

Actually, I am not clear on what the primary purpose for the limitation is.

Perhaps you cold give me some insight in to why it is not done this way?

Answer (score 4):

Comments are considered to be the red-headed stepchild of the Stack Exchange system, and they wanted to discourage too much trivial commenting.

[Here's Jeff's take on it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35552/13295)

It's actually worse than you might know, because every time you fail because of the 5 second rate-limit, the timer gets reset.

Comment: I am referring to the limit on voting up the good comments, which is **not** reset every time I fail. What's the point of limiting me to 1 every 5 seconds, instead of 2 every 10 seconds? I am **not** referring to the limit on posting comments.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, I suppose that could be, I can't keep track of all the rate-limit discussions I've seen on making, voting for and deleting comments.

Comment: I think the timer reset is only for posting comments, not for voting on comments...

Comment: @KerrekSB, well maybe at sometime they changed something, but take a look at [this search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[comments]+rate-limiting).