# Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, voting, voting-limits

I've hit the 40 daily vote limit wall and yet can see on my profile I have 7 votes yet to give to actually reach that ceiling. The votes remain and I am unable to cast them.

According to a recent [blog posting](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/):

> The daily vote limit used to be 30 votes per day; we’ve increased that to 40 votes per day. But the last 10 of those votes can only be cast on questions.

This does not work for me. I cannot upvote any more questions although I have only done 33 votes today.

[image: showing vote total mismatch]

Comment: Does this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256 - make it any clearer?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is totally by design...

If 1 in 3 of your votes are on questions, you will get 40 votes.

If you vote on fewer questions than that you will get fewer votes (lowest is 30)

We just updated the blog

Comment: I've now been hosed three times trying to get to vox populi.  Why in the world would you guys need to play tricks like this?  I missed it by 1 tonight.

Comment: stackexchange is not a game ;)

Answer (score 41):

From the link Chris posted:

> Question votes may be cast at any time during the day. However once you reach the N votes remaining warnings, stuff is set in stone. A question voting spree at the end will still count down.

I interpret that as meaning: Once you have cast 30 votes against answers you have hit the vote limit and can no longer vote, even if you have "question" votes left over.

To quote another comment on that page:

> Agreed. More balanced voting throughout the day would be much better than question-only voting at the end of the day. – Bill the Lizard♦

Comment: Whoa - if that's the case, it's *extremely unintuitive*.  I guess I can imagine it's mainly a technical limitation.

Comment: @Renesis Well if you are going for "How can I use up all of my votes?", then its not particularly intuitive, but not that many people on the site think like that - the vast majority just vote until they can't vote anymore, in which case saying to a user "You can vote, but only on questions, and only for a few more votes" is more complicated than just saying "Sorry, you are done for the day"

Comment: In fact, the vast majority of users never reach this limit anyway :-)

Comment: Disagree.  It's more like "I know I can use 40 as long as I vote on 10 questions.  Wait, I'm out at 33? What?" - Just like the question asker.

Comment: @Renesis Yes but the vast majority of users aren't even aware that there *is* a voting limit - they've never even seen that message, let alone looked up the exact rules as to when it appears.

Comment: I reach the `N votes remaining` warning if I vote on 25 questions, so I guess I reach the `5 votes remaining` warning when I have voted on 10 questions, and 25 answers. But on 25 questions, I need 25/3 = 9 votes on questions, to reach the threshold. Then the system will offer me 10 more votes, plus 5 which I would have had anyway? :) Interesting algorithm.