# Impossible to upvote questions when voting limit for answers is reached

Tags: support, voting, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

I think i have run into a bug with the new voting system. Whenever you have upvoted 30 answsers, you can no longer upvote questions. This makes it impossible to reach the 40 votes limit and therefore impossible to obtain the 'Vox Populi' badge.

Is this intentional in some way, or is it simply a bug?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is intentional or not, but it's certainly possible to get the badge by using more of your daily votes on questions.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But it should still be possible to upvote 10 questions after you have upvoted 30 answers, shouldn't it?

Comment: Have you voted on questions/answers that might have since been deleted (either down or up)? They would still count against your daily vote allocation, but they might not be reflected in the vote totals you're showing.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Just checked. No, I haven't. All questions and answers still exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand the new system you must vote 10 questions **first** meaning as part of the 30 "ordinary" votes you have, and only then you get extra 10 votes.

I might be wrong, but if I'm right this explain what you describe.

Comment: Turns out you are right. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached

Comment: Cheers, nice find!