# Did Stack Overflow remove the 10 additional question-only daily votes?

Tags: support, voting, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

In  [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), Jeff said that Stack Overflow added 10 additional "question-only" daily votes.

> Last month we made voting more visible and added 10 additional "question-only" daily votes to encourage people to vote more on questions, so we can better discern their value.

According to this rule, everyone have 40 votes in a day, if he/she vote on 10 questions and 30 answers. But after I voted 30 times on answers(28 times) and questions(2 times), I got a message said "Daily vote limit reached".

Obviously, I didn't get the 10 additional “question-only” daily votes. Did Stack Overflow remove the 10 additional question-only daily votes?

Comment: No, it has not been canceled. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached) for implementation details.

Comment: @Cody Gray I still don't understand why he can vote 33 times, not 30 times or 40 times.

Comment: You've only cast 24 votes ever on Stack Overflow. Here on Meta, you've cast 30 votes today (not 33). So I'm not sure where you're getting the number 33 from.

Comment: @Cody Gray I means the author who posted the question, not me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 40 votes include 10 votes for questions; if you vote only answers, then the limit is 30 votes. The other limit is that when you see the message saying that you still have 5 votes, you effectively have 5 votes; if you did vote only answers, at that point you cannot vote questions and have more than the 5 votes you have been reported to have.

Comment: How does stackoverflow decide whether give me the 10 additional "question-only" daily votes?

Comment: You just need to use them before you see the various messages saying "You still have X votes." That means the questions should be voted before 25 answers are voted.

Comment: I see, think you. If a user vote on answers reaches 25 times, or he/she vote on questions and answers reaches 35 times, the various messages saying "You still have X votes." will be activated