# Daily vote limit took a downvote feedback into account even though I don't have the downvote privilege

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, voting-limits, post-feedback

In Stack Overflow, I reached my daily vote limit on 39. However, I cast **10+ question up-votes before reaching 25 total** (Q & A votes), but I didn't get the 40 total.
What did happen is I tried to down-vote on 1 answer, but I have less than 125 rep, so it showed the following dialog:

> Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 125 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

I believe it took 1 vote from the 40 limit.

**Edit:** (+info after @RobertLongson comment): Even though the down-vote may appear later, it does not show in my activity page, and the "vox populi" badge shows 39/40 (still not earnt).

I've already read the following questions:

- [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)
- [Separate vote pools for questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers/89547#89547)
- [Daily vote limit hit before reaching actual counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90058/daily-vote-limit-hit-before-reaching-actual-counts)
- [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256)
- [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached/90734#90734?newreg=239ce6501f4c41829e013e19610b6afa)
- [Did Stack Overflow remove the 10 additional question-only daily votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102105/did-stack-overflow-remove-the-10-additional-question-only-daily-votes)
- [Daily vote limit reached; vote again just now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224685/daily-vote-limit-reached-vote-again-just-now)
- [Says I reached my daily vote limit for comment upvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296255/says-i-reached-my-daily-vote-limit-for-comment-upvotes)
  and
- [Maximum voting bug?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2776/maximum-voting-bug).

Still, I think this may be a bug.

---

**Edit 2:**
This is the list of all 39 up-votes, first one around 2:00 am UTC

```
Complete list of up-votes
=======================================================================================================================================================
Num Q/A Link
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985941/how-to-make-dot-match-newline-characters-using-regular-expressions/1985948#1985948
2   A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081446/why-does-my-regex-replace-string-contain-the-replacement-value-twice/27081489#27081489
3   Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584124/recursive-regular-expression-matching
4   A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584124/recursive-regular-expression-matching/12585110#12585110
5   A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414339/recursive-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript/4414453#4414453
6   Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414339/recursive-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript
7   A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719935/regex-with-recursive-expression-to-match-nested-braces/12720266#12720266
8   Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719935/regex-with-recursive-expression-to-match-nested-braces
9   Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349999/converting-pcre-recursive-regex-pattern-to-net-balancing-groups-definition
10  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349999/converting-pcre-recursive-regex-pattern-to-net-balancing-groups-definition/3357040#3357040
11  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813751/get-inner-patterns-recursively-using-regex-c-sharp/9813977#9813977
12  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813751/get-inner-patterns-recursively-using-regex-c-sharp
13  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385984/recursive-pattern-in-regex
14  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385984/recursive-pattern-in-regex/26386070#26386070
15  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1733489#1733489
16  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/5233151#5233151
17  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/7564061#7564061
18  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524570#524570
19  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9
20  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9/16621778#16621778
21  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9/16622773#16622773
22  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit/6479605#6479605
23  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80357/match-all-occurrences-of-a-regex/80387#80387
24  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression
25  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression/172316#172316
26  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator
27  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305853/how-can-i-make-my-match-non-greedy-in-vim/1305957#1305957
28  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305853/how-can-i-make-my-match-non-greedy-in-vim
29  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex
30  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex/3510850#3510850
31  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line/31060125#31060125
32  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java/60161#60161
33  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java/60172#60172
34  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions/400316#400316
35  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764247/why-are-regular-expressions-so-controversial
36  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/how-do-i-access-named-capturing-groups-in-a-net-regex/906514#906514
37  Q   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/how-do-i-access-named-capturing-groups-in-a-net-regex
38  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381097/regex-get-the-name-of-captured-groups-in-c-sharp/1381163#1381163
39  A   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219815/convert-php-closing-tag-into-comment/15219834#15219834
```

---

**Edit 3:**
I was not able to reproduce this behaviour here on meta.

Comment: I found this far from readable with numbers rather than titles on the nine cited questions, and so expanded them.

Comment: @RobertLongson: The system will not later cast any votes on your behalf. They're just rolled in with anonymous feedback. [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259591).

Comment: More likely a post you upvoted was deleted. This cause the vote to "disappear" by all means, but it still counts for the badges etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That was my first thought, but I checked the votes panel, opening every link and I found all posts, and it still shows 39/40 in badge

Comment: You mean in the votes tab you see 40 posts you have upvoted today? All after 12 AM, UTC?

Comment: I added the URLs to the up-votes