# Unintuitive voting limits: 34 votes for me, today

Tags: discussion, vote-count, voting-limits

I am well aware of [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached) and its answers, but I was still surprised at ending up with 34 votes today. The last one being a downvote on a bad question. Now, I cannot downvote other bad questions for more than 5 hours.

The collected statistics show that in total I have spent 37% of my votes on questions, so there is hardly any reason to push me into voting on more questions. So, what is the reason?
Should I refrain from up-voting good answers early in the day, just in case I run into a lot of bad questions late at might? How is this strategy improving the site?

Could we perhaps have an exception for users who have already spent **way** over 25% of the votes on questions?

Comment: It's a game, the winners get 40 votes in.  I've been hosed by this quite a few times.

Comment: `The collected statistics show that in total I have spent 37%` I think  the number of "bonus" votes only varies based on how many questions you have voted on during that day.  But, I'm not disagreeing with you.

Comment: @jonsca - You are right, I just question if this is a good idea. I cannot control if see interesting answers before I see "interesting" questions. A daily quota perhaps isn't the best way? Or possibly it could be modified on grounds of "good behavior"?

Comment: Perhaps calculate the quota at the end of the day and dock the next days 40 if votes weren't cast for the minimum number of questions.  The penalty stays intact, but you don't have to calculate as you go.

Answer (score 8):

You were able to vote 34 times because you voted on 4 questions, and 30 answers. You can vote 40 times if you vote at least 10 questions; for example, if you vote 5 questions, 15 answers, 5 questions, and 15 answers (in this order), then you can vote 40 times.
Once you get the warning about still having 5 votes, that is the number of votes you can still cast.

> So, what is the reason?

The reason is pushing to vote more questions. I guess that there are very good questions that are put on the same level (as for votes) to worse questions, and they want good questions stands out from the bad questions.
The fact more than a quarter of your votes were for questions doesn't influence the purpose of the extra votes, as the extra votes are for pushing to vote questions always, not in a defined timeframe. There are always new questions, and there is always the problem to make good questions stand out. That is also the reason down-votes on questions don't cost reputation to the down-voter.

> Should I refrain from up-voting good answers early in the day, just in case I run into a lot of bad questions late at might?

You should not change your voting behavior; you just vote as you already do, keeping in mind that if you vote 10 questions, your limit is not 30 votes per UTC day. There is nothing that says you have to vote 40 times each day, and if that doesn't happen, nobody will say anything.
Refraining to vote a good answer because there could be very bad question to be down-voted doesn't make sense, as you can still down-vote that question the day after. Following that reasoning, you would not vote any posts, because there could be a better post that needs an up-vote, or a worse post that needs a down-vote; you should probably vote in the 5 minutes before midnight UTC, being sure of reading all the posts, to be able to vote for the best, or the worst post.

> Could we perhaps have an exception for users who have already spent way over 25% of the votes on questions?

If you mean that users who gave at least a quarter of their votes to questions should be free to vote 40 posts, then I don't agree with that.
The purpose of the extra votes is to resolve a problem that there exists until new questions are asked. It doesn't try to push people to use at least a quarter of their votes for questions, but to increase the votes on questions. In the front page, what you see is a list of questions, and seeing a good question having the same score of a bad question is not something that helps about the quality of the site; it is like saying that the site accepts both good, and bad questions, while users should understand that bad questions are not encouraged.

Comment: Any question votes you make before casting 30 answer votes become extras, up to a limit of 10? Is that right? Or is it that you must vote on at least 10 questions before casting 30 votes of either kind?

Comment: Well, maybe. In retrospect I obviously got the "5 votes remaining" after 29 votes. After that I believe I might have voted on 2 questions and 3 answers, so that would be 6 questions in total. My question was rather how my average of voting on 8 questions and 13 answers per day will improve by limiting the voting for today? I have two other questions I *would* have voted for otherwise. :-)

Comment: I would say you have to vote on at least 10 questions before voting on 30 posts (questions or answers).