# Does Vox Populi badge require that all the 40 voted posts are not deleted by end of day?

Tags: support, voting-badges, deleted-posts

After the introduction of Vox Populi badge, I remember ever having used all the 40 votes in one day for three days. The last time was the day before yesterday. However, every time some of the voted questions/answers were deleted before the day ends -usually it are the downvoted posts. My day vote count as visible in my profile also decreased that much, e.g. 39 instead of 40, but I am unable to make another vote the same day. It shows the error that the daily limit has been reached.

Until now, I have not received the badge. Does the badge indeed require that all of the 40 voted posts are not deleted by end of day? In other words, I should not (down)vote posts which are likely to be deleted the same day? Why do I not get the vote on the deleted post back so that I can vote another post the same day?

Comment: I think the badge should be awarded anyway - it's not your fault the post was deleted, you cast all your 40 votes and that what matters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does the badge indeed require that all of the 40 voted posts are not deleted by end of day?

Yes it actually does. Clearly we can not count deleted votes (where you undo), but I am not against counting votes on deleted posts for this case.

> In other words, I should not (down)vote posts which are likely to be deleted the same day?

**No**, it is a bronze badge designed simply to teach you about the 40 vote limit. We never intended for it to **stop** you from voting down bad content. In general people upvote and do not downvote so it is a bit of an edge case.

> Why do I not get the vote on the deleted post back so that I can vote another post the same day?

Actually you do ... as soon as a post is deleted you get the vote back right away.

Comment: Thank you. Wrt the last point, perhaps I did something wrong. I'll remember making screenshots whenever this fails again for me. By the way, I checked the badge award history for other users and it seems that it's been awarded pretty immediately once you hit 40th vote and not only by end of day, is this true? Shouldn't I already have been awared when I got the "Sorry, daily vote limit reached" warning? Another point which may be of importance; I've been awarded the badge the very first day it was introduced, but it was revoked some days later when the badge script turned out to contain a bug.

Comment: @Chichiray - You are also not sure to actually have all your 40 votes per day,  unless you use them in the right order. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103356/unintuitive-voting-limits-34-votes-for-me-today

Comment: @BoPersson: hmm, I'm pretty certain that I used all the 40 votes, it appeared as such in the day vote stats in my profile when I first hit the "Daily vote limit reached". My question:answer voting rate is usually about 3:4, so that should be no problem as well. Or am I missing another catch? After all, I think that I should have tried to vote another type of post at the point I got a vote back from some deleted post. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @Chichiray - One catch is that you have to use your 10 special votes on questions before using 25 votes on answers. Otherwise the "5 votes remaining" condition is triggered and you end up with 30-something votes that day. In my example I got 34.

Comment: Well, I got the badge today, even though one of the posts I downvoted was deleted (it however occurred early today, far before I hit the 40 votes). We'll probably never know why the previous attempts failed until someone else encounters the same. I think it has something to do with the post type of the deleted post. Waffles, thank you for your support :)

Comment: Or, maybe, getting votes back from deleted posts *after* you hit the 40 vote limit isn't working properly. For example, some vote limit toggle has to be turned back or something.