# Where's my Vox Populi badge?

Tags: support, voting-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Vox Populi badge require that all the 40 voted posts are not deleted by end of day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107780/does-vox-populi-badge-require-that-all-the-40-voted-posts-are-not-deleted-by-end)

I was a very good boy yesterday, voting 40 times (and getting the message that told me to wait until the next day before voting again) on a good mix of questions and answers. But I didn't receive the Vox Populi badge for it. What gives?

Comment: Are you sure you voted 40 times?

Comment: It might have been that one of the posts you voted on was deleted. This would mean that your vote doesn't show up in your "Votes Cast" section, but you can't vote again as you have voted 40 times.

Comment: See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107780/does-vox-populi-badge-require-that-all-the-40-voted-posts-are-not-deleted-by-end

Comment: @Shadow: That didn't show up when I searched. Must've not picked the right keywords. Or maybe there's a unicorn somewhere that's in a huff; I dunno.

Comment: Unicorn is likely to be the cause.. the place is crowded with them! ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Vox Populi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/147/vox-populi) requires you to use all 40 votes in a day, but you haven't voted 40 times on any site<sup>1</sup>.

Looking at your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/114848?tab=accounts), the only site where you came close was on Stack Overflow:

> [image: Vote count]

You are allowed to vote 40 times in a day as long as you make sure [10 of those votes are on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256) *before* you get the warning about only have a few votes left for the day.

---

<sup>1</sup>As [ChrisF mentions in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110940/wheres-my-vox-populi-badge#comment-287247), if you voted on a post that was deleted before the badge awarding job ran, [you missed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107780/does-vox-populi-badge-require-that-all-the-40-voted-posts-are-not-deleted-by-end) since it'll look like you only voted on 39 posts.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not surprised it was something like that.