# Vox Populi badge basic-description not accurate enough

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

The basic description of the [Vox Populi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/147/vox-populi) badge says:

> Use the maximum 40 votes in a day.

It is quite confusing and frustrating when you reach 39/40 for the badge and you cannot vote anymore. (see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255876/about-vox-populi-badge) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110940/wheres-my-vox-populi-badge)). I got 37/40 before yesterday and 39/40 yesterday while I reached the maximum daily number of votes (which I assumed was 40).

My understanding of the [badge description wiki for Vox Populi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732) is that, in general, if we want to have 40 votes available, we should vote for 10 questions at least, and quite early:

> - It is possible for the system to restrict you to fewer than 40 votes in a day.
>
>   - You get two types of votes per day: **ten can be used only on questions** ("Q-votes") and 30 can be used on either questions or answers ("QA-votes").
>   - When you vote on a question, the system tries to use your Q-votes before your QA-votes.

So I propose to change the Vox Populi basic description from "Use the maximum 40 votes in a day" to "Use the maximum 40 votes in a day, including more than 10 early questions votes" or "Use the maximum 30 + 10 votes in a day" or something similar. It does not describe all the details, but it would be less confusing.

Comment: Related: *[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732)*

Comment: A simple change might be to just change it to "Vote 40 times in a day". I think the exact rules as per Glorfindel's answer are too complex to put in the description and I think at various stages I've hit the voting limit at somewhere between 30-150 votes.

Answer (score 5):

I can see where you're coming from, but it wouldn't be true; the minimum number of votes on questions is 0. Actually, the maximum votes per day is not even 40. (So you're right, the description is not 100% accurate. But it's hard to be accurate *and* concise.)

The details are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/295232), but let me rephrase the relevant parts here. The initial maximum number of votes per day is 30 (that's what the [Suffrage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/118/suffrage) badge is trying to tell). There are two ways to get more votes:

- You're familiar with the 10 extra votes you can get if you vote on questions.
- When you vote on a post which is deleted later that day, you'll get an extra vote. In this way, you can theoretically get an unlimited number of extra votes, *without voting on questions at all*. I've seen this happen during spam waves, but it could also happen for very low quality answers which get deleted by the review queue or the moderators (quickly enough).

In both cases, that extra vote will still count towards your daily *total* which is shown on your profile, and what the Vox Populi badge checks.

Comment: @Noil  the meaning of **can be** is not the same as **must be**. Regardless, if you vote only on answers you won't get the Vox badge because the maximum number of votes for answers is 30. If two or more posts get deleted during the day, I think you can cast those two votes again. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90479/whats-the-difference-between-suffrage-and-vox-populi-badge/254598#254598

Comment: @Noil I've rephrased my answer and hope this makes things clear. If not, well, it's apparently too difficult for me to explain.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні I'm not sure what you are referring to because the previous comments have been deleted by somebody. But I agree with you, as far as i undersand, the only way to have 40 votes available (except the very special case pointed by Glorfindel) is to vote for at least 10 questions among the 40 question/answer votes. This is what feeds my request to change the basic-description of this badge.

Comment: @Noil the now-deleted comment said (I know because I kept the page open) *According to the FAQ "You get two types of votes per day:* **ten can be used only on questions ("Q-votes")** *and 30 can be used on either questions or answers ("QA-votes")." So it means that* **10 votes on questions are necessary** *to reach the 40 votes, doesnt it?*

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні thanks for retrieving the previous comments!! My understanding of the doc: if you don't use 10 Q-votes, then you will  have 30 available votes only (except the very special case pointed by Glorfindel). So if you want to reach 40 votes, you *must* vote for at least 10 questions (again except the very special case pointed by Glorfindel).

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is 40 votes. You achieved only 37/40 and reached your maximum due to voting on answers as well. E.g.:

- you can vote 40 times if all the votes are on questions
- you can vote 30 times if all the votes are on answers

Basically to earn the badge you have to vote a lot on questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My post is rather a feature request to improve the basic description of this tag, which is confusing otherwise.