# Daily vote limit reached on 37 votes

Tags: support, status-bydesign, questions, voting, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)
>   [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

Today I have reached the daily vote limit three votes too soon.

Why did this happen?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Also see: [Does Vox Populi badge require that all the 40 voted posts are not deleted by end of day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107780/does-vox-populi-badge-require-that-all-the-40-voted-posts-are-not-deleted-by-end)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a [limit of 30 all-purpose votes per day and 10 question-only votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits).

The tricky part is that you have to spend your questions-only votes first.

Comment: Is it really by design that the *order* in which you cast your votes matter? If so, what is the rationale for it? Why is it accepted to vote on 10 questions then 30 answers, but not 30 answers then 10 questions?

Comment: @corsiKa The feature was designed to specifically encourage voting on questions. I don't know the rationale behind making the order matter, but I think it's somewhere here on meta. I'll try to find it. It never particularly made sense to me either, to be honest.

Comment: @corsiKa [This is the best I could find](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/155160). Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh well that makes sense. Instead of requiring answer votes before question votes like it was before, it requires question votes before answer votes. Riiight. Part of me is all pumped up because 'omg that has to be a bug' or something similar. The other part of me, the part I'm trying to encourage to come out and play more, is like 'oh, well that's unfortunate.' Thanks for your help though. At least I know I'm not alone in really understanding the rationale for it.