# Why Can't I use all 40 votes per day?

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

I like to vote a lot more now, and try to use up all my votes each day. Yesterday I had an issue where **it only let me use 36 votes**. I figured it was a bug, and would pass. Today I got stopped at 39.

[image]

I waited a few hours and tried again, but to no avail

[image]

This bug is not just on my profile, but on the **Users > Voters > Weekly** page. The new week just started so you can see it clearly.

[image]

This error is on Super User. I have not tried to replicate it on any other SE sites yet.

Comment: @Sathya that explains it perfectly, thanks!

Comment: cheers @SimonSheehan