# Can't reach the 40 votes in a day for Vox Populi?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

I was doing some searches last week and today and I noticed I can't get above 39 votes in a day?  Last week it was something like 35 approximately, but today I topped out at 39, preventing me from getting the Vox Populi badge.

When this happened last week as soon as could vote again, some internal counter got reset to 0, even though it was about 7pm at night CST.

Is this by design or is something else going on here?

Comment: You need to vote on a certain number of questions, not just answers. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90734/131713

Comment: As for the counter reset: Midnight UTC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to vote on at least 10 questions, then 30 *more* answers or questions. 10 of your votes are reserved for questions.