# Daily vote limit reached on 39 votes instead of 40 votes

Tags: bug, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

I am trying to cast my 40th vote but a prompt is displayed saying "Daily vote limit reached" on 39 votes. What could be the possible reason for it? How can i cast my last 40th vote?

Comment: [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

Comment: Can i know the reason of down vote for this question?

Comment: Downvote due to [lack of research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=daily+vote+limit+reached)

Comment: We can ask a new question if we don't find the same.

Comment: This is also your [lack of research](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)

Comment: Please try to be realistic and understand the issue faced by people. Otherwise there is no use of such communities.

Comment: @FurqanSafdar - When you ask a question, first search for similar questions. For example, when I search meta for [your exact question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Daily+vote+limit+reached+on+39+votes+instead+of+40+votes+) name, the first 10 or so hits are the same question. If **none** of those work for you, link a bunch of them in your question and clarify _why_ they fail to meet your needs. Then you shouldn't get down voted because you’re showing your research, right now it looks like you didn’t check before posting.

Comment: Thanks Mike for explaining the correct way of posting questions. I will follow your instructions from now onwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get 40 votes if you vote for at least 10 questions, and those votes must be casted before you vote for 30 answers. For example, this means:

- If you vote for 30 answers, and 0 questions, your daily limit is 30
- If you vote for 40 questions, and 0 answers, your daily limit is 40
- If you vote for 5 questions, 15 answers, 4 questions, and 15 answers (in that order), your daily limit is 39

When you get the message "you still have 5 votes," that is the number of votes you still have before to reach the daily limit. Suppose you voted for 25 answers, and you get that message; at that point, you can vote for questions, but you still have 5 votes left, and you cannot vote for 10 questions.

Comment: Really helpful, but i couldn't get this information in the earlier post related to this question that is why i asked this question for better answer.

Comment: @FurqanSafdar - Closing the question is not a punishment for you, but SO's way to link the questions to get them organized.

Comment: Is this principle still in effect in Aug 2020?