# Where's my Boater hat?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash-2013

I used up my alotted 40 votes yesterday (on RPG.SE) and didn't get the Boater.

> [image]
>   use the maximum of 40 votes in a single day

Is this a bug, an inaccurate description, or does I not English right?

This is extremely concerning because, as you can see, the jaunty angle perfectly matches my Gravatar.

Comment: you english right not do

Comment: @Cruncher But my reading unright or just wrighting not right mean you?

Comment: be I funny, not no I either

Comment: @Cruncher English.SE grave roll do we make!

Comment: tie bow do is angle good very also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anna is correct, this one tripped me up at first too. According to the voting limits you can vote 40 times in a day. *However*,

- 10 of those votes must be on questions
- **and** the 10 votes on questions must occur *before* you hit the 5 votes left warning

So, that is a total of 30 answer or question votes, and 10 question votes - in the order noted above. **[See here for more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90726/178816)**

I just earned the boater hat a few minutes ago (so it is not that delayed, maybe 5 minutes). I would suggest doing as you said in a comment here and... VOTE ALL THE THINGS again :)

Comment: Aha! I didn't know about the 30/10 split, that would have been it.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure none of the posts you voted on was deleted (although you should still have it).

To check that, upvote one of my posts randomly...

Jokes apart, there is a slight delay for this particular hat. It took a little while for it to appear this morning on my profile.

Gotta admit that's the perfect angle..

> [image]

Comment: Hm, that's possible, though hard to check. It was a mix of older and newer posts, so I don't have a very good way to make a checkable list. I suppose I can just VOTE ALL THE THINGS again.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Vote till you can't vote anymore. Also I updated my answer. You're better off with that bow tie.

Comment: Hm, you speak truth.

Answer (score 6):

You cast *39* votes on December 16.

Also, note that currently you have to make sure you vote on 10 questions first, or else your votes per day will be capped at 30.