# Up/Down votes are not refunded

Tags: support, voting

I reached my vote limit of 40 up/down votes today, and then tried to switch one of my downvotes to an upvote after a question was clarified. The downvote was reverted successfully; however, the upvote did not happen, as I "reached my daily vote limit". I think this may be a bug, but I don't know if this is erroneous behaviour or just by design. Can someone explain why this happens and if it is by design, why this was the decision made?

Comment: The limit isn't fixed 40, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90734/152859). You probably tried this on answer, but you can vote only on questions once you reach 30 daily votes. (I think.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard He took one of his votes and reversed it. The count doesn't change. It goes from `a` to `a-1` and back to the same ol' `a` votes

Comment: @ShadowWizard That might explain; I voted on the question a few days ago and today I voted on mostly answers.

Comment: Your votes for the day are your votes for **that** day. If you undo your vote from a couple of days ago, that won't affect your votes for today.

Comment: @Catija Oh right this is a stupid question lol xD I completely forgot that; that would be why :P

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, it is now tomorrow.

Comment: @Catija yay :D "it is now tomorrow" ... lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comments, you downvoted a question several days ago but tried to change your vote today after they edited their post.

You'll have to wait until the reset to actually upvote the post as you've undone a vote from another day, not today, which is why you can't change your vote to an upvote.