# Can't upvote either questions or answers, though I'm only at 34 today

Tags: bug, voting

I am stuck at 34 votes on MathOverflow. Some previous answers like [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached) say that this is because the 40 votes should be 30 for answers, 10 for questions. But, it seems different in my case as I get the error popup whether I'm voting on answers or on questions. So I can't get closer to 40 votes by just voting on questions.

[image: This shows I'm at 34 votes]

[image: This shows I've hit the limit]

Both screenshots are from within a window of 1 or 2 minutes.

Comment: You probably voted on posts that were later deleted. It still counts towards the daily limit, as far as I remember.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes) Waffles' answer is a concise explanation of the rules. What Shadow says is also true but happens less often.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the posts were deleted within the past few hours? @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I was voting throughout the day and didn't really keep track of how many were questions and how many answers, but thanks for the pointer @Glorfindel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only vote a certain number of times per day. Once you voted on 25 answers a countdown starts and you can then only vote 5 more times.

If you want to use your maximum of 40 votes in a day you therefore need to vote on some questions before you vote on 25 answers. You'd need to have voted on 10 or more questions before you voted on 25 answers, but it looks like you only voted on 4 questions.

Comment: Hmm, that could be possible. There were some really good answers amongst those I voted on today. Thanks!