# Please relax the search rate limits for moderators

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, rate-limiting

For a discussion on a meta site where I'm a moderator, I'm in the process of compiling a few statistics.

> You can only perform 6 searches within a 60 second window, please wait a moment and try again.

*sigh*

None of the usual workarounds such as using the API or the data dump or Google are usable because many of my searches involve **deleted questions.**

Please relax (not lift, but relax to a reasonable rate) the search rate limits, at least for moderators. We're trying to do our job here, and a handful of moderators per site aren't going to overload the servers.

I'd be satisfied with an alternative such as accessing deleted questions through the API or the data explorer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kinds of frequent searches are you performing, the inability to perform them of which is hindering your moderation abilities?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm a moderator on a beta site. There, handling flags (which indeed doesn't require many searches) is only a small part of being a moderator.

Comment: Curious. It's been days since I've had to do a search.  Searching is not part of my normal workflow at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, [here's the answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/is-it-good-that-story-identification-questions-are-so-well-rewarded/1137#1137). This type of community building question — evaluating a question type — is fairly common on beta sites. Moderators are expected to participate, because they are supposed to be community leaders; and our ability to search deleted posts helps when we're trying to evaluate quality metrics.

Comment: Good idea. This has been biting me more and more often too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Moderators will get double searches in the next build.  The primary reason for the search throttle is I/O speed on our web tier, since we don't keep the entire Lucene index in RAM (risky, very risky - and possibly not at all stable).  The amount of I/O it takes combined with previously low speed of the SATA drives in those servers meant I/O contention was a real factor.

We're taking a longer look at search now, possibly with an architecture change (a dedicated pair with the index in memory for example) that'll eliminate the need to throttle (well, much higher anyway - still blocking crazy scraping bots) with a slew of other improvements.

Stay tuned, we'll have some more around this soon enough.